# Escaping a square bracket in a MongoDB regex / PCRE

Tags: regex, mongodb, pcre

I need to query a MongoDB database for documents whose field `x` starts with `[text`. I tried the following:

`db.collection.find({x:{$regex:/^[text/}})`

which fails because `[` is part of the regex syntax. So I've spent some time trying to find how to escape `[` from my regex... without any success so far.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Tried db.collection.find({x:{$regex:/^\[text/}}), doesn't work either

Comment: @ThomasWeiss  why you used `regex` ? `find({"x":"[text"})` also works or [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28280/regex-bug-in-mongodb) helps more

Comment: @yogesh a simple 'find' would look for an exact match, not fields starting with [text, but your link provided hints to the solution, so turn it into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using backslash `\` in front of the square bracket as below :

```
db.collection.find({"x":{"$regex":"\\[text"}})
db.collection.find({"x":{"$regex":"^\\[text"}})
```

Or

```
db.collection.find({"x":{"$regex":"\\\\[text"}})
db.collection.find({"x":{"$regex":"^\\\\[text"}})
```

It returns those documents which starts with `[text`

For ex:

In documents contains following data

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55644128dd771680e5e5f094"), "x" : "[text" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("556448d1dd771680e5e5f099"), "x" : "[text sd asd " }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55644a06dd771680e5e5f09a"), "x" : "new text" }
```

and using `db.collection.find({"x":{"$regex":"\\[text"}})` it return following results :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55644128dd771680e5e5f094"), "x" : "[text" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("556448d1dd771680e5e5f099"), "x" : "[text sd asd " }
```

Comment: No you need the ^ character to match the start of the string. The version that works is: db.collection.find({x:{$regex:"^\\[text"}})

Comment: I guess your query would also match "x":"hello[text"